# How could I change shopping cart color in woocommerce when it is disabled?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with the ecommerce "add to cart" button (I am using WooCommerce). The button appears in gray when I have not selected neither the color or the size of the product, and it is only when I select both oh them that the button is enabled and turns black. My problem is that I want the button to be black from the beginning, regardless of whether it is enabled or not.
How can I do it?

Comment: consider adding the HTML code for your button so as to get more chances of getting a reply

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you default button solution since you havent provided any code or url to your page to inspect it.

Disable button rule. Place it in css file with higher priority of woocommerce.css file or use !important rule.

```
.woocommerce button.button.alt.disabled {background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;}
```